# How to structure this relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, erd

Basically I'll be having 3 tables that have relation. They are: `users`, `departments` and `company`.

The issue I have is this:

- A `company` can have **many** departments
- A `department` can only be attached to **one** company
- A `user` can only be part of **one** company
- A `user` can be part of **many** departments

This is essentially what the table relation would look like:

```
                    ____________________
                    | | | |            |
                    | | | |            |
--------      --------------      -----------
| user |      | department |      | company |
--------      --------------      -----------
 |   |         | | | | |               |
 |   |         | | | | |               |
 |   ___________________               |
 |                                     |
 |                                     |
 |                                     |
 _______________________________________
```

<sup>*The above multiple `|` lines show an option, so the "company" above has 4 departments and so on.*</sup>

Now my question is this, How should I structure the relation tables?

Should I have `user_departments`, `user_company` and `company_departments` tables?

That would essentially look like this:

```
--------------------
| user_departments |
--------------------------------
| id | user_id | department_id |
--------------------------------

----------------
| user_company |
-----------------------------
| id | user_id | company_id |
-----------------------------

-----------------------
| company_departments |
-----------------------------------
| id | company_id | department_id |
-----------------------------------
```

Or are there any other alternatives for me to consider/implement instead of the path I'm going as it seems it'll just keep growing complex?

Comment: Is there a need for the relationship between user and company if the others remain?

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades I need to know what company the user is apart of, usually as a department isn't permanent, it could simply be removed if desired

Comment: From the description, there's only *one* **many-to-many** relationship, between `user` and `department`.  The other **one-to-many** relationships can be implemented by adding a foreign key column to the entity table, e.g. add `company_id` column to the `user` table, and to the `department` table. (Of the three tables you show, you only need the `user_department` table, you don't need the other two.)

Comment: probably the best ascii erd i've ever seen.

Comment: @pala_ why thank you ! I feel it's always better described with an image ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially making redundant relationships. You should have no need for a company_departments, company_id will just be a field of the departments table to reference the company a department is a part of. Likewise, you won't need a user_company table, but you will need the user_departments one; that is due to the user-department relationship actually being many-to-many.

With the example you've given, you should only need four tables.

```
company: company_id, other company info (such as name) 
department: department_id, company_id (referencing the company record), other department info 
user: user_id, company_id (referencing the company record), other user info
user_departments: user_id, department_id, perhaps information such as user's role in department, or if you want historical data preserved dates assigned to and removed from department
```

Comment: The company can remove departments, and if a user is only a member of the department that gets deleted, how would I know which company they are associated with?

Comment: @Darren, Like the departments table, the user table should have a company_id.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the layout in the format you used:

```
---------
| users |
--------------------------------
| id | name | company_id | ... |
--------------------------------

-----------
| company |
-------------------
| id | name | ... |
-------------------

-----------
| departments |
--------------------------------
| id | name | company_id | ... |
--------------------------------

--------------------
| user_departments |
--------------------------------
| id | user_id | department_id |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: The `department` table should also have a foreign key column `company_id` referencing `company(id)`.